# showing format according to device using bootstreap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstreap3 I want to show some different format according to deviec
if large and medium device i want to use left middle and right as 2,8,2 column and for mobile and small devices i want to show content of middle will all 12 column.

I am using following code for this but this is not working perfectly for me.

```
<div> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2" ></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2" ></div>
  </div>
```

This is working properly with large and medium device for sm and xs it is not full width.
How to achive this?

Comment: add col-sm-{{col}} or col-xs-{{col}}

Comment: Your code works good for me (all columns on mobile/tablet have 12 columns width).

Comment: It is providing some space at left and right not full width